# This program takes a long time to terminate. How can I optimise it?

Tags: c#, optimization

I've been writing a program to perform a kind of pattern matching in XML and text files. When my program reaches this section of the code the CPU usage goes very high and the performance slows down to a point where the program appears to be frozen, but actually it is not. Depending on the input (number of text files and their content) it may take up to several hours to complete the task. I'm looking for a more efficient way to rewrite this section of the code :

```
List<string> CandidatesRet = new List<string>();

for (int indexCi = 0; indexCi < Ci.Count - 1; indexCi++)
{
    // generate all sub itemset with length-1
    string[] allItems = Ci[indexCi].Split(new char[] { ' ' });
    for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Length; i++)
    {
        string tempStr = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < allItems.Length; j++)
            if (i != j)
                tempStr += allItems[j] + " ";
        tempStr = tempStr.Trim();
        subItemset.Add(tempStr);
    }

    // THE PROBLEM BEGINS HERE 

    foreach (string subitem in subItemset)
    {
        int iFirtS;
        for (int indexCommon = indexCi + 1; indexCommon < Ci.Count; indexCommon++)
            if ((iFirtS = Ci[indexCommon].IndexOf(subitem)) >= 0)
            {
                string[] listTempCi = Ci[indexCommon].Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                foreach (string itemCi in listTempCi)
                    if (!subitem.Contains(itemCi))
                        commonItem.Add(itemCi);
            }
        allCommonItems.Add(commonItem);
    }

    // generate condidate from common item
    foreach (string item in oldItemsetCi)
    {
        bool flagCi = true;
        foreach (List<string> listCommItem in allCommonItems)
            if (!listCommItem.Contains(item))
            {
                flagCi = false;
                break;
            }
        if (flagCi)
            CandidatesRet.Add((Ci[indexCi] + " " + item).Trim());
    }
```

There are many nested loops, and I know this is the problem. What do you recommend to improve it?

Comment: This question would be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How big are the text files that you're parsing? Also, instead of defining an accumulator have you thought about using an iterator to save on memory usage? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx

Comment: @Tombatron: the files are not big but for example 10 100kb files take more than 1 hour to be processed

Comment: To be able to say a `more efficient way to rewrite this section of the code`, we must understand what you really want to do. `I've been writing a program to perform a kind of pattern matching in xml and text files` is not much explanatory

Comment: @I4V: This only a very small part of the code, this is an Artificial Intelligent project that search through text file which contain the called APIs by different programs, then according to the number of times each API has been called it assigns a value to the API from 1 to -1, this only a small part though.

Comment: When you run this program with a profiler attached, where is it telling you that it's spending most of its time?

Comment: I think you need to check your algorithm to make it faster. without understanding algorithm, it is difficult to say how to improve it (on this forum, most are developers, unfortunately, not algorithm expert). If you mean the UI is frozen, one way to improve is: do calculation in another thread, instead of UI thread. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, actually when I faced this problem it took me several hours to find what exactly is triggering it, so I started by removing forloops, This way I ensured that other parts of the code is fine, and logically this section of the code is supposed to be very timely because there foreach loops within a forloop and that forloop iterates according to the values in a text document, I've been thinking getting the foreach loops out of the for loop but I haven't been able to find a way so far

Comment: at a quick check, I can see a problem. allCommonItems is in loop-loop, and it is not initilized, so it will grow as you process more data. same as commonItem. I assume they are List<string> or List<list<string>>. That's why you have to use loop-loop to check .Contains(), which is slow. Use a Dictionary to save all commonItem, it will make it much faster. P.S. since the code is so simplified, really can not say much more.

Comment: @urlreader: Thank you very much, I'm trying this out

Comment: @Jack Have you done any code profiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you were to re-write your code to be more performant there's still a chance the work you are doing is CPU bound and therefore if it doesn't yield enough so that the main thread can handle it's UI related event processing, you will always experience a so called freeze in your application.

There are several techniques to counter this:

- Use a BackgroundWorker to get the job done
- Offload to a separate dedicated thread
- Utilize the Task library
- Utilize the Thread Pool directly
- <s>Use Application.DoEvents</s> Better yet, **DON'T EVER!**.

(Most of these techniques are beyond the scope of this answer.) See this article on [implementing this technique](http://stuff.seans.com/2009/05/21/net-basics-do-work-in-background-thread-to-keep-gui-responsive/).

The core idea is that if you have CPU or IO bound work and your UI main thread doesn't have enough time to do its event processing this will be a problem that can't be avoided.

Comment: Don't sprinkle "Application.DoEvents" in your code.  It makes it much more difficult to reason about the order that your code runs in.  Without Application.DoEvents, all of your methods will run atomically with respect to one another.  With Application.DoEvents, anything can happen.  If you really need something to run on a background thread, go through the trouble of running it on the background thread and then abstract that fact away using a common asynchronous pattern.  Mentally make "Not really recommended" bold and a much larger font

Comment: @KenWhite I modified the answer. I know DoEvents is kind of an ugly workaround but I wasn't aware of the re-entrant issues it can introduce to an application.  I figured for the most simplistic of situations it's fine but I'd rather fix the answer since you were nice enough to not downvote.  We all have something to learn on stackoverflow.

Comment: +1. Much, much better. :-) I'll remove my previous comment to clean up the clutter.